# Count specific character in each line of at text and remove this character in a specific position until this character has a specific count

Tags: bash

Hello i need help with one script that its on Solaris system:

I will explain the script analytically:

i have these files :

i)

```
cat /tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt

    201807300000000004 
    201807300000000005 
    201807300000000006
    201807300000000007
    201807300000000008
    201807200002056422
    201807230003099849
    201807230003958306
    201806290003097219
    201806080001062012
    201806110001633519
    201806110001675603
```

ii)

```
cat /tmp/BadTransactions/test_data_for_validation_script.txt

20180720|201807200002056422||57413620344272|030341-213T |580463|WIRE||EUR|EUR|20180720|20180720|||||||00000000000019.90|00000000000019.90|Debit||||||||||MPA|||574000|129|||||||||||||||||||||||||31313001103712|BFNJKL|K| I P P BONNIER PUBLICATIO|||FI|PERS7
20180723|201807230003099849||57100440165173|140197-216U|593619|WIRE||EUR|EUR|20180723|20180723|||||||00000000000060.00|00000000000060.00|Debit||||||||||MPA|||571004|106|||||||||||||||||||||||||57108320141339|Ura Basket / UraNaiset|||-div|||FI|PERS
20180723|201807230003958306||57206820079775|210489-0788|593619|WIRE||EUR|EUR|20180721|20180723|||||||00000000000046.00|00000000000046.00|Debit||||||||||MPA|||578800|106|||||||||||||||||||||||||18053000009026|IC Kodit||| c/o Newsec Asset Manag|||FI|PERS
20180629|201806290003097219||57206820079775|210489-0788|593619|WIRE||EUR|EUR|20180628|20180629|||||||00000000000856.00|00000000000856.00|Debit||||||||||MPA|||578800|106|||||||||||||||||||||||||18053000009018|IC Kodit||| c/o Newsec Asset Manag|||FI|PERS
20180608|201806080001062012||57206820079441|140197-216S|580463|WIRE||EUR|EUR|20180608|20180608|||||||00000000000019.90|00000000000019.90|Debit||||||||||MPA|||541002|129|||||||||||||||||||||||||57108320141339|N FN|K| IKI I P BONNIER PUBLICATION|||FI|PERS7 
20180611|201806110001633519||57206820079525|140197-216B|593619|WIRE||EUR|EUR|20180611|20180611|||||||00000000000242.10|00000000000242.10|Debit||||||||||MPA|||535806|106|||||||||||||||||||||||||57108320141339|As Oy Haikkoonsilta|| mannerheimin|||FI|PERS9
20180611|201806110001675603||57206820079092|140197-216Z|580463|WIRE||EUR|EUR|20180611|20180611|||||||00000000000019.90|00000000000019.90|Debit||||||||||MPA|||536501|129|||||||||||||||||||||||||57108320141339|N ^NLKL|K| I P NJ BONNIER PUBLICAT|||FI|PERS7
```

The script has to check each line of the

`/tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt` and if the strings are on

the `/tmp/BadTransactions/test_data_for_validation_script.txt` it will create a

new file `/tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_NEW_20180730.txt

From this new file it will count all the " | " in each line and if its more than 64 it will delete the " | " in 61th posistion of the line . This will be continued until its line has 64 pipes.

For example if one line has 67 " | " it will delete the 61th , then it will check it again and now has 66 " | | so it will delete the 61th " | " , etc... until it reach 64 pipes.So all the line have to have 64th " | ".

Here is my code , but in this code i have managed to delete only the 61th pipe in each line , i cannot make the loop so that it will check each line until it reach the 64 pipes.

I will appreciate it if you could help me.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/xpg4/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

while read line
do

grep "$line" /tmp/BadTransactions/test_data_for_validation_script.txt

awk 'NR==FNR { K[$1]; next } ($2 in K)' /tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt FS="|" /opt/NorkomC
onfigS2/inbox/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt > /tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_NEW_20180730.txt

sed '/\([^|]*[|]\)\{65\}/ s/|//61' /tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_NEW_20180730.txt

done < /tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt > /tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_NEW_201807
30.txt
```

Comment: show what the correct output should be.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, in this problem you have several pieces of code.

- You need to read a file line by line
- Check each line against another file
- Examine the matching line for the occurrences of "|"
- Delete recursively the 61st "|" until the string will remain with 64 of them

You could do something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
count() { ### We will use this to count how many pipes are there
  string="${1}"; shift
  char="${1}"
  printf "%s" "${string}" | grep -o -e "${char}" | grep -c .
}
file1="/tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt" ### File to read
file2="/tmp/BadTransactions/test_data_for_validation_script.txt" ### File to check for duplicates
file3="/tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_NEW_20180730.txt" ### File where to save our final work
printf "" > "${file3}" ### Delete (eventual) history
exec 3<"${file1}" ### Put our data in file descriptor 3
while read -r line <&3; do ### read each line and put it in var "$line"
  string="$(grep -e "${line}" "${file2}")" ### Check the line against second file
  while [ "$(count "${string}" "|")" -gt 64 ]; do ### While we have more than 64 "|"
    string="$(printf "%s" "${string}" | sed -e "s/|//61")" ### Delete the 61st occurrence
  done
  printf "%s" "${string}" >> "${file3}" ### Save the correct line in the third file
done
exec 3>&- ### Clean file descriptor 3
```

This is not tested, but should work.

N.B. Please note that I am giving for granted that grep will return only one occurrence from second file...
If it is not your case you have to manually check each value with something like:

```
for value in $(grep -e "${line}" "${file2}"); do
  ...
done
```

EDIT:
For systems like Solaris or others that doesn't have GNU grep installed you can substitute the count method as follow:

```
count() {
  string="${1}"; shift
  char="${1}"
  printf "%s" "${string}" | awk -F"${char}" '{print NF-1}'
}
```

Comment: I think your script will work in my case .
From what i mention this is Solaris system . So grep -e -o options are option illegal to used.
i tried to use egrep but its the same result .And GNU grep is not installed on ther server neither if i use also /usr/xpg4/bin/grep .

Could we do that with awk also right ?

Comment: Yes, you can use whatever you want [: For instance you can use `wc -l` instead of `grep -c .`

Comment: /usr/xpg4/bin/grep: illegal option -- o

Could you please suggest any other method to do that ?

Thanks!!

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have the possibility to test grep on a Solaris system, by the way you can substitute `grep -o` with whatever you like.
If you want to use awk you can use `printf "%s" "${string}" | awk -F"|" '{print NF-1}'` instead of `printf "%s" "${string}" | grep -o -e "|" | grep -c .`... UI will edit the answer with this.